# Correct way to set the default selected option from model in dropdown menu with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Need to set the default value form here - `status`.

```
"projectSteps":{
        "red":{
            "date":"11/03/2015",
            "status":"ready"
        },
        "green":{
            "date":"11/03/2015",
            "status":"not ready"
        }
        "blue":{
            "date":"11/03/2015",
            "status":"done"
        }
    },
```

Here is dropdown json:

```
"status":[
       {"value":"ready"},
       {"value":"not ready"},
       {"value":"done"} 
]
```

Here is html with ng-repeat for options:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(step, q)  in steps">
       <td>{{$index}}</td>
       <td>
          <label for="stepsStatus">label</label>
          <select data-ng-model="filterItem.status" id="stepsStatus" required class="form-control" ng-options="a as a.value for a in q.status"></select>
       </td>   
    </tr>
```

Getting the values as a dropdown, but can't set the default value from `projectSteps`.

```
data-ng-model="filterItem.status" 
$scope.filterItem = {
            status: $scope.projectSteps
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this way I showed the icon just for the selected category.

```
 <select id="stepsStatus" required ng-model="q.status[0]" ng-options="a as a.value for a in q.status" ></select>
 <span class="{{q.status[0].icon}}"></span>
```

So JSON file is also updated with pair for icon:

```
"projectSteps":{
    "red":{
        "date":"11/03/2015",
        "status":"ready",
        "icon":"done"
    },
    "green":{
        "date":"11/03/2015",
        "status":"not ready",
        "icon":"not ready"
    }
    "blue":{
        "date":"11/03/2015",
        "status":"done",
        "icon":"ready"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your ng-model to the value you want selected:

in the html:

```
<select id="stepsStatus" required class="form-control" 
    ng-options="a as a.value for a in q.status" ng-model="selectedStep"></select>
```

and in the controller:

```
$scope.selectedStep = // set whatever you want selected
```

Comment: Yeah, but i need 'selected step' to get from `"projectSteps":{}` for each item  (red, green, blue) as they a repeated in the table and each of them has a dropdown with values.